# Chrome switch of white list domains

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Is there a switch for Chrome I can use to block all domains except from my local server - `http://localhost:4200/`?

Context - I am running Chrome with `--disable-web-security` switch, but often find forgetting it has security disabled and then using it for Googling and stuff... So I want my machine to prevent me from doing stupid things.

Comment: You can find the list of switches here: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: I know. The one I tried doesnt seem to work